# Open file as authenticated windows user

Tags: php, file, authentication

I want to echo a file from a php web site.
The file is located on a file share in the same domain

> (\nas\projects\project.txt).

I already activated windows authentication on the web site and when I

```
echo $_SERVER['AUTH_User']
```

the correct user is displayed (the user I am connecting to the website).

But when I try to open the file with DirectoryIterator, I get the error message

> "the user name or password is incorrect".

How can I access this file with the authenticated user (in the server variable auth user)?

EDIT:
I still have no idea why it is not working.. When I try to access the file from the localhost where I am running the web site, I have access to it, but when I open the web site from another client but with the same user and browser, I have no chance to access it (I have access in Windows explorer to the file)... Still no ideas?

EDIT2:
Still the same problem with PHP 7.0.1. I am confused why this is not working.

BR
Raphi